# IE bug: Button image background

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, background-image

I'm dealing with a weird bug that I don't manage to fix.

It's a known bug and in fact I found on the Web several solutions, but unfortunately they don't work in my case!

Here is a screenshot that shows how the button appears on the other browsers, instead on IE it appears completely white.

[image]

The CSS rules that I am using are the following:

```
background:url('http://www.legrandclub.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/Send-Message.jpg');
width:113px;
height:25px;
border:0px;
```

Which additional rule should I use?

Thanks

Comment: Can you make a test case? http://jsfiddle.net/ / http://jsbin.com/

Comment: I made a test on both websites and the button is rendered correctly.

Comment: Then follow these steps. Use http://jsbin.com/. Empty the HTML pane. Copy the entire HTML of your page that's showing the problem into the HTML pane. Add all CSS used by your page inside a `<style></style>`. I'm assuming that JavaScript has nothing to do with this problem, so forget about it. Save your demo, and link to it here.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Here is the link http://jsbin.com/udocej/2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem coming from `bp.css`, line ~660:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#ededed',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

That gradient is drawn on top of everything else. The rest of your button is hiding beneath it.

Now that you know what the problem is, you should be able to solve it. You need `filter: none` on `#send_reply_button`, or you need to otherwise override/remove the `filter`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps just build a button in css too...

```
 <a href="send.htm" class="abutton">Send Message</a>

 a.dbutton {
    font-family: Verdana; font-size: 13pt; font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #e60000; 
    margin-top: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    margin-left: 21%;
    margin-right: 21%;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:block;
    padding:8px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    text-align:center;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    -o-border-radius:5px;
    border-radius:5px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice but I would like to keep an image as background (if it's possible).